# Calculating local time with UTC offset

Tags: php

This is probably basic, but I can't seem to think straight when it comes to offset.

Currently, I display time by converting datetime from db like this:

```
date('g:i A', strtotime($given_date));
```

However, now I get an additional value from db, which UTC shows offset time in minutes, Currently it is:
    $offsetTime = -300;

So, to get the current local time, in this case I need to subtract, something like this

```
date('g:i A', strtotime($given_date) - $offsetTime * 60);
```

But what if offset is a positive number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You state that $offsetTime already is a negative value

```
 $offsetTime = -300;
```

Therefore you must add it to the date

```
date('g:i A', strtotime($given_date) + ($offsetTime * 60); // use plus-char
```

Because

```
+ (-300 * 60) = + -18000 = - 18000
```

If you have a positive offset of let's say 120 you will get:

```
+ (120 * 60) = + 7200
```